# How etiquettical is it to start off a professional email with 'Hey'?

Tags: word-usage, formality, email, salutations

I've been wondering, why whould folks avoid the usage of `Hey` to greet someone/team as the mail starts, did that *really* read grotesque? What could be the alternatives other than the conventionals?

Comment: I don't think many people use *hey* as greetings. Some do use it, but the word is also used to attract attention from somebody or to start swearing to strangers depending on your tone. Your e-mail can't deliver your tone.

Comment: "Hey" is better for informal emails. Try "Hello" for formal ones.

Comment: Related: [Are greetings and salutations redundant in an e-mail?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/are-greetings-and-salutations-redundant-in-an-e-mail) and [Is a salutation necessary in an email to an unknown person?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174472/is-a-salutation-necessary-in-an-email-to-an-unknown-person)

Comment: Look at it this way - you wouldn't walk up to someone in the street and start a conversation with 'Hey', it is grossly impolite.  So, why put it in an email.

Comment: "Hi" is informal but not as informal as "Hey".

Comment: Few things say "delete me" more persuasively than "Hey," IMO.

Comment: I'd only use it if communicating with a familiar who I knew to accept such greetings.

Comment: @Chenmunka - Actually, it would not be unusual at all to walk up to a stranger on the street and say "Hey, can you tell me how to get to Carnegie Hall?"

Comment: @HotLicks - Only if I wanted to hear, "Practice!"

Comment: You might as well try "Yo dawg".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dear Mr/Ms <surname>
```

is still the correct formal way to start an email.  Stick with that.  Note that you should use Ms with women even if you happen to know what their marital status is.

Save "Hey" for good friends.

This is a good guide for email etiquette, particularly when mailing companies.

https://www.career.vt.edu/JobSearchGuide/Email.html

Comment: I agree with this, *except* the part about "Ms". Some people strongly object to Ms. Starting an email by annoying someone is not good! In general in the UK, I'd advise starting with *Dear {First name}*, whether they're male or female.

Comment: Ah, perhaps yes.  Yeah, *Dear <first name>* is probably safer in the UK.

Comment: I still used Mr/Ms as a sign of respect and it usually taken as such.  The only problem with the title is getting it right.  I get plenty of mail from India and I'm never quite sure.  Additional.  I have witnessed "shock" at the use of the word "dear".  The graceless think it's too familiar.