# How does one formally address and email when the gender of the recipient is unknown?

Tags: word-choice

What is the correct way to address the recipient of a professional email, when only the last name of the person is known? Would it be more polite to say, for example "Dear Mr/s Smith" or "Dear A. Smith"
I don't have much experience writing formal emails and could really use some advice

Comment: Personally, I would just call the organization and find out. Otherwise, it's simply a case where you don't know the recipient's name, for which see *[“Dear Sir or Madam” versus “To whom it may concern”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2112),* *[Title in a letter to an unknown person](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147868)*, and *[What is the best salutation to use in cover letter when I don't have contact information?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3331)* among others.

Comment: I solve this problem by dispensing with the Dear So-and-so line, and substituting it with "Good morning" or "Good afternoon."

Comment: Below the recipient's address, simply begin the text of your letter; e.g., "I am writing to express my interest in the position of Chief Financial Officer for your organization." etc.

Answer (score 3):

The late great William Safire answered this question in 1989. His recommendation:

```
Greetings:
```

William Safire, [The Mulvihill Perplexity (On Language)](http://www.nytimes.com/1989/06/25/magazine/on-language-the-mulvihill-perplexity.html), 25 June 1989, *New York Times*.